# What is PyQt's equivalent to tkinter's canvas?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, tkinter, pyqt4

I've recently decided to try switching from `tkinter` to `PyQt`, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do what I could do with `tkinter`'s canvas widget.

After some googling, it seems like it's either `QPainter`, `QPixMap`, or some combination thereof.  There also seems to be something in `Qt` called `canvas` but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Could someone explain what I should be using to draw lines and shapes on the screen, and point me to a good tutorial on how to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you need here is [`QPainter`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qpainter.html#details) class, Quoting from PyQt Sourceforge documentation:

> The QPainter class performs low-level painting on widgets and other
>   paint devices.
>
> QPainter provides highly optimized functions to do most of the drawing
>   GUI programs require. It can draw everything from simple lines to
>   complex shapes like pies and chords. It can also draw aligned text and
>   pixmaps. Normally, it draws in a "natural" coordinate system, but it
>   can also do view and world transformation. QPainter can operate on any
>   object that inherits the QPaintDevice class.